# How to execute remote COM dlls?

Tags: java, php, .net, windows, dll

I am having a problem about running a COM dll remotely on windows PCs.

I have a COM dll registered in all the client stations (windows) of my network and a .NET application hosted on a server in my network.

There is a POST request, which will receive the client ip as a parameter and the application will execute a remote call to the dll installed on the pc of the ip passed in the request.

I already used PHP with XAMPP, I could verify that it works locally, although XAMPP reboots a few times (I still do not know the real reason). one solution would be to install locally on each client a network xampp server with a php application receiving requests and running the dll locally, but would be impractical in view of the amount of computers available on the network.

Still with PHP, I saw that it would be possible to remotely call this faq from the php documentation, but to no avail. I'm starting .NET with C # because I believe being native (windows) will be better/easier to get results, but I have not yet found a plausible solution to run the dll remotely.

As a result, I will have the opening of the COM dll program already registered in the client pc (ip passed in the POST request).

Has anyone gone through this or do you have any idea how to run a dll remotely with .net, java, php or other technology?

Comment: sounds like you'd want to write an app that runs on the client machine with a browser embedded in it.  If your app launches the browser, it can register classes with the browser/web pages.

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms  Or, if you want Java, use JavaFX.  Or, embed Chrome.